# Передать двумерный статический массив в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели

Возникает проблема в передаче двумерного статического массива в функцию

```
int ** transp(int ** M, int a, int b)
```

Пытался просто передать как `int ** array` 
`int A[3][4];
transp(A, 3, 4);`

> [Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[3]' to 'int**'

1. Как правильно передать статич массив в функцию . При этом функция должна также принимать динамические массивы. Перегрузку, шаблоны и STL не предлагать.
2. Статические 2D массивы хранятся в памяти линейно. Динамические хранятся тоже линейно или нет?
3. Какую связь имеет статический 2D массив с указателями?

Comment: покажите как обращаетесь

Comment: обновил вопрос. посмотрите

Answer (score 13):

Если у вас имеется массив, объявленный как

```
int A[3][4];
```

то нешаблонная функция, принимающая данный массив в качестве аргумента может выглядеть, например, как

```
void f( int ( *a )[4], size_t n );
```

и вызываться как

```
f( A, 3 );
```

Или ее можно объявить как

```
void f( int ( &a )[3][4] );
```

и вызывать как

```
f( A );
```

Что касается данной функции

```
int ** transp(int ** M, int a, int b);
```

то вы не можете в нее передать массив, объявленный как

```
int A[3][4];
```

То есть передать можно, используя различные ухищрения, но скорей всего функция не будет работать так, как вы предполагаете.

Есть такой универсальный подход. Это интерпретировать любой двумерный массив, как одномерный, и передавать значения размеров каждой размерности массива.

Например,

```
void f( int a[], size_t m, size_t n );

//...

int A[3][4];

f( reinterpret_cast<int *>( A ), 3, 4 );
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void f( int a[], size_t m, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) a[i * n + j ] = i * n + j;
    }
}    

int main()
{
    const size_t M = 3;
    const size_t N = 4;
    int a[M][N];

    f( reinterpret_cast<int *>( a ), M, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << a[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
 0  1  2  3 
 4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10 11
```

Если же писать программу на C, а не на C++, то там есть массивы переменной длины, и поэтому вам было бы проще.

В C++ для этих целей лучше использовать стандартный класс `std::vector`

Например,

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v( 3, std::vector<int>( 4 ) );
```

Что касается вашего вопроса

> 2)Статические 2D массивы хранятся в памяти линейно. Динамические
>   хранятся тоже линейно или нет?

то если вы будете распределять его в памяти как двумерный массив, то естественно его элементы будут храниться линейно по строкам. Например

```
int ( *a )[4] = new int[3][4];
```

А что касается этого вопроса

> 3)Какую связь имеет статический 2D массив с указателями?

то любой массив в выражениях (за редким исключением) неявно преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент.

Comment: А как сделать эту функцию универсальнее, чтобы она принимала любые A[x][y] ?

Comment: @neko69 Что значит "любые"? Если любые двумерные массивы с любыми значениями размерностей, то сделайте ее шаблонной.

Comment: Шаблонная, в смысле `template <class T>` ? Без этого нельзя?

Comment: @neko69 Если вы хотите иметь дело именно с двумерными массивами, то без этого не обойтись.

Comment: @neko69 Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: сейчас обнаружил, что сервис тестирования принимает `int ** transp(const int * const * m, int a, int b)`

Answer (score 5):

В gcc сделать это совсем просто.

Вы можете передавать в функцию размерности матрицы (достаточно только "низших") и обращаться к элементам по индексам естестственным образом. Например:

```
void func (int n_lines, int n_columns, int array[][n_columns]) {
     array[0][0] = array[n_lines - 1][n_columns - 1]; 
}
```

К сожалению g++ (и c++) не поддерживает такую передачу матриц в функцию. Поэтому проще всего (обладая знанием, что все элементы матрицы располагаются в памяти последовательно, сначала первая строка, за ней вторая и т.д.) передать в функцию адрес первого элемента матрицы, а в функции рассматривать ее как одномерный массив.
Естественно, пересчитывать индексы придется самому.

Вот пример файла, в котором представлены обе версии программы и результаты его запуска:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat c1.c
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <iostream>
#endif

static int aa[4][3] = {
  {11, 12, 13},
  {21, 22, 23},
  {31, 32, 33},
  {41, 42, 43}
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
void
func_matrix (int n, int m, int *x)
{
  x[0] = x[(n - 1) * m + m - 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m || !puts(""); j++)
      std::cout << x[i * m + j] << ' ';
}
#else
void
func_matrix (int n, int m, int x[n][m])
{
  int i, j;
  x[0][0] = x[n - 1][m - 1];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < m || !puts(""); j++)
      printf("%d ", x[i][j]);
}
#endif

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
  func_matrix(4, 3, &aa[0][0]);
#else
  func_matrix(4, 3, aa);
#endif
}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc c1.c && ./a.out
43 12 13 
21 22 23 
31 32 33 
41 42 43 
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ c1.c && ./a.out
43 12 13 
21 22 23 
31 32 33 
41 42 43 
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Если вопросы еще остались, задавайте.

**UPD**

Вот вариант с указателями на строки "плотной" матрицы.

Берем статическую матрицу, делаем для нее массив указателей, передаем его в функцию транспонирования, которая делает в динамической памяти "плотную" транспонированную матрицу и возвращает новый массив указателей на ее строки.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **
make_lines_ptrs (int *mx, int a, int b)
{
  int **p = (int **)malloc(a * sizeof(int *));

  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    p[i] = mx + i * b;

  return p;
}

int ** 
transp (const int * const * m, int a, int b)
{
  int *mx = (int *)malloc(a * b * sizeof(int));

  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
      mx[j * a + i] = m[i][j];

  return make_lines_ptrs(mx, b, a);
}


void 
pri_mx (const int * const * m, int a, int b)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < b || !puts(""); j++)
      printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
}

static int aa[4][3] = {
  {11, 12, 13},
  {21, 22, 23},
  {31, 32, 33},
  {41, 42, 43}
};

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int **pl = make_lines_ptrs(&aa[0][0], 4, 3);
  pri_mx(pl, 4, 3);
  int **tr = transp(pl, 4, 3);
  pri_mx(tr, 3, 4);
}
```

Ну, память перед выходом Вы уж сами освободите?

Comment: а передать динамический массив этой же функции можно?

Comment: После всех ответов я еще больше запутался. Почему в с++ нужно передавать `&aa[0][0]` , разве `aa` не будет являться указателем на первый элемент?

Comment: Если он также последовательно расположен в памяти, то да. Если же под динамическим Вы понимаете массив, который организован как массив указателей на строки (каждая независимо размещается оператором new (или malloc), то, конечно же нет.

Comment: С точки зрения здравого смысла -- `aa` это тот же адрес, что и у `aa[0][0]`, но вот компиляторы считают, что нет, что у `aa` другой тип: `int (*)[3]` (и переубедить их можно только явным приведением типа).

Comment: тогда как сделать такую функцию, которая одновременно работала и с динамическими (new) и со статическими массивами?

Comment: Простыми способами -- никак. Точнее, всегда можно использовать препроцессор в Си и шаблоны в крестах, но не факт, что вся программа станет проще. (пока я не советую Вам углубляться в метапрограммирование)

Comment: в задании дана подсказка с прототипом функции - `int ** transp(const int * const * m, int a, int b)` И функция должна принимать оба вида массивов. Или нужно сделать функцию, которая определяла бы тип массива и дальше вызывала нужную функцию?

Comment: Мне кажется они имеют в виду "нормальные" (без new каждой строки) массивы. Ведь ничто же не мешает выделить память под массив в динамической памяти одним куском -- `malloc(a * b * sizeof(int))`

Comment: я запутался с памятью в динамических массивах. Если для каждого `**int` выделять отдельно память для строки - то массив в общем будет разбросан по памяти. Если выделить память `a * b`, а потом расставить внутри указатели на  начала строк (new вызывается только 2 раза) - то он будет храниться в памяти последовательно?

Comment: Да, возможно Вы правы и они имеют в виду массив указателей на строки. Я попробую обновить ответ, с примером транспонирования, который соответствует прототипу `int ** transp(const int * const * m, int a, int b)` и его использование для традиционного статического массива.

Comment: @neko69, обновил ответ, как обещал.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<int aRows, int aCols>
void func(int (*data)[aRows][aCols]){}
...
int a[5][3] = {0};
func(&a);
```

кроме передачи значений самого массива получаем его размеры через aRows и aCols.