# как передать двумерный масив в функцию?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

как передать двумерный масив в функцию чтобы так работало?

```
int massiv[5][7];

functia(massiv, 5, 7);
```

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Ну никак вы не хотите поверить, что `int[][]` - это ни разу **НЕ** `int**`.

Comment: @Harry, я просто никогда с таким не сталкивался. Фигня какая-то, это косяк Си. Нелогично нифига. Размер массива пишется как часть типа. Вон чё выводит: `error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int*’`.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Потому размер и является частью типа, что для каждого размера идет свой расчет смещения от начала блока памяти. То, что у меня в ответе `m[i*d2+j]` - поэтому можно *не знать* только первую размерность, а вот остальные знать *обязательно во время компиляции*.

Comment: @Harry, на самом деле, можно немножко постараться, и научить компилятор считать чуть чуть получше =) Это просто условность для упрощения жизни

Comment: @Harry, но то, что Си порождает новые типы просто из размера массива - не очень. Получается, Си знает о размере массива, но программист вынужден передавать его в функцию, чтобы не было переполнения .

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον С знает о размере объявленного массива, но не переданного в функцию - только если в нее вы передаете его с размером - что-то типа `f(int a[][7])` - словом, чтобы размер был обязательно известен при компиляции, иначе просто невозможно скомпилировать нужный код...

Comment: В общем, т.к. адресная арифметика в многомерных массивах ломается, а многомерные массивы порождают новые типы в зависимости от 2й и последующих размерностей, то варианта 2: 1) отказаться от многомерных в пользу одномерного, либо 2) указывать тип в прототипе функции целиком: `void functia(int m[][7], int d1, int d2)`

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Да ничего не ломается, не придумывайте. Как хорошо заметил  ARHovsepyan - надо выучить и понять :)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189577/multidimensional-array-indexing-using-pointer-to-elements

Comment: @user7860670, т.е. чтобы это гарантировано работало, нужно пользоваться этим хаком с кастом в `char*`? По мне лучше избегать такой фигни вовсе...

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον что лучше избегать - тут я полностью согласен

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Например, так:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void functia(int *m, int d1, int d2)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < d1; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < d2; ++j)
            cout << m[i*d2+j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int massiv[2][3] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6}};

    functia(&massiv[0][0], 2, 3);

    // Ещеодин вариант - так:
    functia((int*)massiv, 2, 3);

}
```

Только, как видите, обращаться как `m[i][j]` уже не получится - придется самостоятельно с индексами работать...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111570/discussion-on-answer-by-harry------).

Comment: Для будущих читателей: см. в чате обсуждение, есть здесь неопределенное поведение или нет.

Answer (score 5):

Каждый двумерный массив имеет свой тип.
`int[row][4]` имеет тип `int(*)[4]` или `int[row][22]` имеет тип `int(*)[22]`, независимо от значения константного выражения `row`, поэтому, при передаче он все равно игнорируется, и нужно будет в функцию передать этот размер. Однако, передача любым таким способом, делает функцию не универсальной _ придется написать эту же функцию для массивов с различным количеством столбцов(количество элементов в строке). Более универсальные способы, это передать указатель на начало и две размерности(как указан в ответе `Harry`, и никакого UB не может иметь место), или же написать шаблонную функцию:

```
template<int row, int col>
void some_func(int(&arr)[row][col]);
```

Вот  пример определения и использования такой функции:

```
template<int row, int col>
void some_func(int(&arr)[row][col]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            arr[i][j] = i + j;
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
int main() {
    int A[3][4];
    some_func(A);   
    return 0;
}
```

В функцию void functia(int *m, const int d1, const int d2)  можно передать любой фрагмент двумерного массива, а также динамический массив, поэтому она более универсальна, но если код функции не тривиальна, нужно быть очень внимательным, дабы не допускать ошибок с индексами. Зато шаблонная относительно безопасна, хоть и не так универсальна. Можно без головной боли использовать C++ контейнеры: `std::array,   std::vector` и т.д., элементами которых являются контейнеры фиксированного размера(количество столбцов) или `std::valarray` со срезами **std::slice** или **std::gslice**.

Comment: UB может быть, уже вчера обсуждали. Вот ответ на англоязычном SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189577/multidimensional-array-indexing-using-pointer-to-elements).

Comment: @Παν μέτρον άριστον, вчера обсуждали, однако это не означает, что в обсуждении правы те, кто так считает. Вы  не так поняли. Неопределенное поведение можно получать и без функции, работая неправильно с индексами, и способ передачи в функцию тут не причем, а важен сам код функции и правильная передача размеров.

Comment: @Παν μέτρον άριστον. По такой логике, спокойно можно получить UB и в функции, принимающий std::vector. Если ссылаться на другие ответы, то и я могу привести пример. Вот ответ на SO.ru  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464373/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e

Comment: Я всё так понял. Нельзя перебирать многомерный массив как одномерный, без приведения к `char*` (а это хак и костыль, так лучше этого не делать вообще).

Answer (score 3):

Сразу скажу, что этот способ лучше не использовать. Следующая возможность есть в С, но некоторые С++ компиляторы поддерживают её. Почти всегда лучше использовать контейнеры из STL. Но если вдруг Ваш компилятор поддерживает VLA, то можно писать так:

```
void functia(int rows, int cols, int arr[rows][cols])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            cout << arr[row][col] << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Вот пример использования:

```
int main()
{
    int arr1[2][3] = 
    {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6}
    };

    int arr2[5][5] =
    {
        {25, 24 ,23, 22, 21},
        {20, 19, 18, 17, 16},
        {15, 14, 13, 12, 11},
        {10,  9,  8,  7,  6},
        { 5,  4,  3,  2,  1}
    };

    cout << "Arr1:\n";
    functia(2, 3, arr1);
    cout << "Arr2:\n";
    functia(5, 5, arr2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если необходима работа именно с массивом массивов, то имеет смыл передавать по ссылке. Это также избавить от необходимости дополнительно передавать его размеры:

```
using t_Massiv = int[5][7];
functia(t_Massiv & massiv);

t_Massiv massiv{};
functia(massiv);
```

Comment: Это по большому счету ничем не отличается от передачи `functia(int m[5][7])` - в этом случае вам тоже не нужно передавать размеры массива. Вернее, как и в вашем случае - вы передаете их в типе.

Comment: Теперь что, для каждого массива написать отдельную функцию?... Смысл функции теряется.

Comment: @Harry в `functia(int m[5][7])` размер массива (верхнего уровня) не передается, так как `m` является указателем.

Comment: @user7860670 Получается еще круче, чем со ссылкой :)

Answer (score 0):

Стандарт запрещает передавать как аргумент указатель на массив неизвестных размеров. Можно передавать указатель как `int*` а потом сменить на тип нужных размеров, но не все компиляторы это позволят. Выходом может послужить написание собственного класса.

```
// g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -Wextra -Wpedantic massarg.cpp -o massarg
# include <iostream>
void functia( int * pt,int l,int r){
  
  // warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘m’ [-Wvla]
  // стандарт запрещает массивы переменной длины
  int (&m)[l][r] = *(int (*)[l][r])pt;
  // m - это ссылка на массив указанных размеров

  m[4][4] = 7 ; }

int massiv[5][7];
int massiv2[50][70];

class VArray {
public :
  VArray(int,int);
  ~VArray();
  int & Elt(int i ,int j){return pointer[i*rows+j];}
  int Lines()const{return lines;}
  int Rows()const{return rows;}
private :
  int * pointer ;
  int lines ;
  int rows ;
} ;

VArray::VArray(int l,int r) {
  lines = l ;
  rows = r ;
  pointer = new int [ size_t(l) * size_t(r) * sizeof(int) ] ; }

VArray::~VArray() {
  delete [ ] pointer ; }

void functia2( VArray & arr ){
  arr.Elt(4,4) = 7 ; }
  
int  main(){
  functia((int*)&massiv,5,7);
  std::cout<<"massiv[4][4]="<<massiv[4][4]<<std::endl;
  functia((int*)&massiv2,50,70);
  std::cout<<"massiv2[4][4]="<<massiv2[4][4]<<std::endl;
  VArray va (10,20);
  functia2(va);
  std::cout<<"va.Elt(4,4)="<<va.Elt(4,4)<<std::endl;
}
```

Результат при компиляции в `g++` :

```
$ ./massarg 
massiv[4][4]=7
massiv2[4][4]=7
va.Elt(4,4)=7
```