# Программа крашится при записи данных в матрицу

Tags: c, файлы, матрицы

Нужно считать из файла матрицу, после этого вывести её на экран. По неизвестной причине в методе `file_getData` при попытке записи чисел в матрицу A программа крашится, причём происходит это, даже если попытаться ввести данные с клавиатуры. С чем это может быть связано?

Файл открывается без проблем (по крайней мере, ошибок не выдаёт).

Вот код:

```
void file_getData(int** A) {
    
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("files/input.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("FILE_NULL");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("File is open!\n");
    
    int i;
    
    for (i == 0; i <= 2; i++) {+
        printf("Cycle started!\n");
        fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &A[i][0], &A[i][1], &A[i][2]);
        printf("Line scanned!\n");
    }
    
}

int main() {

int i, j;
int A[2][2];
file_getData(*A);

for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
for(j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передать двумерный статический массив в функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464373/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1):

Вы создаете матрицу размером 2х2 элемента, и обращаетесь к элементу с индексом 2. Такого элемента нет, индексы считаются с нуля: 0, 1, 2 - тут 3 элемента. Увеличьте размер матрицы.

Comment: Нет, матрица создаётся 3 на 3. Всё работает правильно, если прописать элементы матрицы напрямую в коде

Comment: @luciferuus, Нет, здесь `int A[2][2]` создаётся матрица размером `2x2`. Если разделить размер массива `A` в байтах на размер одного элемента массива в байтах, то получится четыре: `sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0][0]); // == 4`. [Тест](https://ideone.com/6FZSru)